# HashMap background color value for Listview

Tags: java, android, colors, background-color

I need to pass personal color

`<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>`

in HashMap like this

`temp.put(COLOR_COLUMN, String.valueOf(R.color.colorPrimary));`

when I read the value I do this:

`if(map.get(COLOR_COLUMN) != null){
            int color = Integer.valueOf(map.get(COLOR_COLUMN));}`

and the I setBackgroundColor(color) of my TextView

but value is something like 2131492900 and color is grey very different from the starting color I set

How can I solve?

Thank you

Comment: Please show the declaration/initialization of the "temp" variable

Comment: Why are you parsing the hex color value to integer? You should get string value and then convert the hex to color. Or set the hex color

Comment: (1) what happens if you `setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimary)` directly? (2) Try logging the TextView's background color to compare, with `((ColorDrawable)textView.getBackground()).getColor()`, before and after the change, does that value make sense? (3) Do you really want to keep an int as a string in a hashmap? What's that use case?

Comment: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/conversion/decimal_hexadecimal.shtml

Comment: @kapsym HashMap temp = new HashMap<>()

Comment: @orip (3) if I keep color value in HashMap directly like int when I set holder.txtFirst.setBackgroundColor(map.get(COLOR_COLUMN)) doesn't work because the type is String not int

Comment: @simvar77 any question left as you didn't accept the answer yet? Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resource (like *R.color.colorPrimary*) in Android is actually represented by a *resource id* in the form of an integer. It's not the actual *color value*. To get the color value you can use the provided `int getColor(int id)` method. See also [Accessing Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html) in the Android Developers Guide.

A correct way to save the resource's id and reuse the color would be:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> temp = new HashMap<>();
temp.put(COLOR_COLUMN, R.color.colorPrimary);
int resourceId = temp.get(COLOR_COLUMN);
view.setBackgroundColor(getColor(resourceId));
```

As an alternative you can also directly save the color's integer representation (and not its resource id):

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> temp = new HashMap<>();
temp.put(COLOR_COLUMN, getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
int color = temp.get(COLOR_COLUMN);
view.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

If for any reason you need to save the resource's id as a String you can do so of course:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> temp = new HashMap<>();
temp.put(COLOR_COLUMN, String.valueOf(R.color.colorPrimary));
int resourceId = Integer.parseInt(temp.get(COLOR_COLUMN));
view.setBackgroundColor(getColor(resourceId));
```

I assumed your `COLOR_COLUMN` variable is an integer.